# How to get a property used in a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is that possible to get back a property that I pass as a paramter to a jQuery plugin.

Sample:

```
$("selector").pluginFunction({ prop1: "test"});
```

Then I want to further get this property value back.

something like

```
var x = $("selector").pluginFunction().giveMyValueBack().prop1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: The plugin would have to implement a way for you to get it. Not all plugins are created in the same way.

Comment: Is there a specific plugin for which you need this?  Plugins can use different conventions.

Comment: I am working with Isotope. I wanto to bring back the filter property that I set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of i dont know what this plugin does you could append that value as data to the element itself.

Write:

```
$('selector').data('prop1', 'test');
```

Read:

```
$('selector').data('prop1');
```

Eventually this is overhead. But without knowing how and if the plugin stores that value its not that easy possible to answer.

Assuming your using jquery.

Comment: Thanks.. I was expecting that all jQuery plugin would use a kind of pattern for it. But that is ok.. your answer is good. tks a lot

Comment: I'm pretty shocked this was chosen as the answer over mine. Not only does it require more code, but also is inefficient. And, consider the scenario when there are data-* attributes already on the element that may possibly interfere with the attributes you are passing to the plugin init. Also, if the element is deleted, so is the data. Having a separate object for the properties is cleaner, less code, and less likely of any conflict.

Comment: Its just one possible solution. i especially dont like the "global" behavior of your answer but thats an opinion. Also it could be desired behavior that the data is deleted if element is deleted. Next point is there could be a lot of data for the same plugin for different selectors. There are so many things we dont know. So maybe he just went with the one which fits his needs best.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your plugin properties as a separate object, and then passing that object to the pluginFunction. For example.

```
var pluginData = { prop1: "test"};
$("selector").pluginFunction(pluginData);
```

Then you can always just refer to the pluginData object.

```
var prop1 = pluginData.prop1;
```

Comment: Cool idea. So obvious, yet that hasn't occurred to me despite how often I retrieve my jQuery UI slider parameters as, e.g., `$("#myslider").slider("options","step");`.